# I wanna make a raspberry pi car using an RC car. I would like to know if the servo multiplexer is necessary?

Tags: pi-3, wifi, wireless, servo, cars

I've asked this question in the Robotics Stack Exchange and I am asking here as this is kind of important and I need some answers fast. My apologies if this is rude or if it causes problems in any way.

So I'm working on a project and it involves making a raspberry pi car, be it from scratch or with the help of can rc car. I chose the latter. Now the problem is I don't really have servo multiplexers being sold anywhere in my country, Bangladesh, so I have no idea how to get a hold of them. I read that their main function was to convert radio signals to PWM signals so that it could be sent to either the servo or the servo driver which would than be sent to the servo. But my project really require the radio control portion of the car, as I would like to control it through wifi with the help of my computer.

So I wanna know firstly and clearly, what is the main function of a servo multiplexer?

Secondly, since I'm not planning on using any sort of radio communication with the car and the remote control but only plan on controlling the car using wifi and my computer, will I really need a servo multiplexer?

Thank you

Comment: The Pi is irrelevant to any answer, so the question is off topic for this site.  You don't want to use radio but want to use wifi?  wifi is radio.  I don't know what you mean by servo multiplexer.  It's not a term I have seen used.  The Pi can send servo signals from its GPIO without any additional hardware.

Comment: @joan I was talking about https://www.servocity.com/4-channel-rc-servo-multiplexer this. Could you recommend another stack exchange I can post it in if its too irrelevent here? My apologies.

Comment: A servo multiplexer is a box that get a multichannel PWM signal from an RC control and send only the portion of the signal to a servo that belongs to this servo. It is part of the receiver box of your remote control. The box where you connect the servos to. For a raspberry you don't need a multiplexer. It receives the wifi signal an has separate PWM pins that can control the car servos. There is a pin limit, but two servos should be possible.

Comment: The link you gave to @joan points to a another kind of Servo multiplexer. This can extent one PWM source to 4 target servos and you can select to which. That part can you use if the Raspi would not have as many PWM pins as you have servos in your project. As far as I know (I'm not deep into it) there are 2 PWM channels with more than 10 pins. That should be enough.

Comment: Regarding somewhere where you can post this, you already mentioned Robotics.SE; there is also [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).  However, while the policy here is not explicitly defined, most SE sites **do not allow cross-posting**, so unless you want your question closed or deleted everywhere, only post it to one site at a time.  If you do not get sufficient attention after a day or so, then delete it yourself and ask somewhere else.

Comment: Tip: The majority of people who ask technical questions online probably "want answers fast" so that is not a great way to introduce yourself.  If you really need immediate help it you might want to learn how to use IRC: http://electronicschat.org/  Good luck!